# debian - lampp - opening files in sublime and permissions

Tags: linux, debian, sublimetext3, lampp

I am testing on a localhost virtual machine with debian.
I have installed lampp.

I have all the files in the htdocs owned by `www-data.www-data` and `chmod 755`.
I have added my user to the group of `www-data`.

If I open a file in a text editor, in this case sublime, it will ask me to authenticate every single time I save the file.

I know I should maybe run Sublime as root user, but is there any other way?
thanks!

Comment: Ok I had added myself to the group but I didn't logout and login again, so problems was very stupid sorry about that

Comment: please don't add "solved" to the title of your question, but instead `accept` the correct answer. if nobody posted the correct answer yet (and you found one yourself), add your solution *as an answer* and `accept` it. (however, @YuriyZhigulskiy's answer is indeed correct, so you should accept it instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not a owner of this file and you have no permissions to write into this file. You make read and execute permissions to group.

The permissions should be `775`.

Comment: Hi Yuri, I am not the owner but I am in the group. The permissions are already set at 755.

Comment: @jsabina your permissions are `755` (aka `-rwxr-xr-x`) but they should be `775` (aka `-rwxrwxr-x`) so the *group* is allowed to *write*; actually the permissions should be `664` (aka `-rw-rw-r--`) for *files* and `775` (aka `-rwxrwxr-x`) **only** for *directories*.